# How can I get total time, my KEYCLOAK server is taking on every incoming HTTP request?

Tags: jboss, keycloak, redhat, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

Is there any way with which we can calculate the total time taken by KEYCLOAK server on every incoming HTTP call?

Comment: Maybe by processing/mining access logs of the http server in front of your KC? Or, perhaps by using a custom authenticator that wraps the requests you want to monitor and times them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Keycloak Metrics SPI https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi

From that metrics endpoint they have a field `keycloak_request_duration` https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi#keycloak_request_duration which displays a histogram